# AS soon as I use the GET command in python selenium, it shows an InvalidArgumentException Error to me. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, selenium

This is the error I get whenever I try to use the driver.get() command in my code. I was trying to get my class' team code on teams using selenium module (by cracking it).
I even tried reinstalling selenium. all my browsers and chromedriver is upto date. Also the folder in which the chromedriver is, exists in the environment path.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:/Users/[my name]/OneDrive/Desktop/Html and python Codes/team-code 8c.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver.get("teams.microsoft.com")
  File "C:\Users\[my name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 436, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\[my name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\[my name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0028FDC3+2555331]
    Ordinal0 [0x002277F1+2127857]
    Ordinal0 [0x00122CD0+1060048]
    Ordinal0 [0x00115763+1005411]
    Ordinal0 [0x001145DD+1000925]
    Ordinal0 [0x001146B6+1001142]
    Ordinal0 [0x001243FA+1065978]
    Ordinal0 [0x00177BAD+1407917]
    Ordinal0 [0x00167B0C+1342220]
    Ordinal0 [0x001775FA+1406458]
    Ordinal0 [0x00167976+1341814]
    Ordinal0 [0x001436B6+1193654]
    Ordinal0 [0x00144546+1197382]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00429622+1619522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004D882C+2336844]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003223E1+541697]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00321443+537699]
    Ordinal0 [0x0022D18E+2150798]
    Ordinal0 [0x00231518+2168088]
    Ordinal0 [0x00231660+2168416]
    Ordinal0 [0x0023B330+2208560]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x769AFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D97A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D97A6E+238]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

Comment: Just a wild guess... Can you add "https://" at the beginning and try?

Comment: OO that actually worked, LOL thank you btw